# Minimum pumping length of regular language

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I know the method to the find the minimum pumping length of regular language by constructing minimal DFA and finding the number of states but I am not able to quite understand why is it working.

For example, $L = (10)^*$.
Here minimum pumping length is 1 by constructing DFA.
But by pumping lemma, how can there be a string of length 1 belonging to $L$? As pumping lemma says the string $S$ should be such that $|S| \le p$ and $S$ should belong to $L$, where $p$ is the pumping length, and here there is no string of length 1 belonging to $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example in fact demonstrates that the pumping length can be smaller than the number of states in the minimal DFA. In your case the minimal DFA contains 3 states, but the pumping length is 2.

The pumping length of a language $L$ is the minimal $p$ such that every word $w \in L$ of length at least $p$ can be written as $w = xyz$, where $|xy| \leq p$, $y \neq \epsilon$, and $xy^iz \in L$ for all $i \geq 0$.

If $L$ contains no words of length $p$ that's not problematic at all. For example, the pumping length of $\{ w \}$ is $|w|+1$. In that case the pumping property holds vacuously.

Comment: The answer was minimum pumping length can be atmost 2 and minimum 1. So **1** was the answer and **not 2**. And yes for finite languages, I know pumping length is |W| + 1. Can you please tell how can it be 1?

Comment: The minimum pumping length is a single number. It's either 1 or 2. According to my definition, it is 2 rather than 1. Perhaps you're using a different definition which doesn't require $|xy| \leq p$.

Comment: When we find the minimum pumping length using minimal  DFA, the answer is longest path from initial state without a cycle right ? So even with minimal DFA, the answer comes out to be 1.

Comment: It really depends on the definition of "minimum pumping length". I have given my definition. What is yours?

Comment: The one is wikipedia which is same as yours. Even my textbook uses the same.

Comment: Great. In that case the pumping length for $(10)^*$ is 2, since the word $10 \in (10)^*$ cannot be written as $xyz$ with $|xy| \leq 1$, $y \neq \emptyset$, and $xy^iz \in (10)^*$ for all $i \geq 0$. Indeed, the decomposition must be $x=\epsilon$, $y=1$, $z=0$, and $xy^0z = 0 \notin (10)^*$.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! So the minimum pumping length would be number of states in longest path from initial state without a cycle in the minimal DFA right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this characterization. You can try proving it and see if it works.

Comment: L = 10(11*0)*0. For this language, I think it's 4. Am I correct.

Comment: It seems like you have a different question.

Comment: It's just slightly a different one. I don't think it would be good to make a separate question for this.

Comment: It's community standards. Even if you ask the question, the reply would be – why do you think that the answer is 4? Have you tried to prove it? We're not here to check your answers. We're here to help you understand the material.

Comment: "Your example in fact demonstrates that the pumping length can be smaller than the number of states in the minimal DFA. In your case the minimal DFA contains 3 states, but the pumping length is 2. "--- what about NFA?
 
10(11*0)*0. -- and there is no denying the fact that the pumping length is 4 here, here also we can build a nfa with 4 states. does NFA gives us proper pumping length?

Comment: No. For example, take $1^*+0^+1^n$, which requires $n+O(1)$ states but has pumping constant $O(1)$.