# Are number of states in a NFA same as Pumping length?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

So i was reading a post on [Minimum pumping length of regular language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84563/minimum-pumping-length-of-regular-language) where Yuval Filmus has proved that a pumping lemma might have lesser number of states than a minimal DFA. But What about NFA's? Are NFA's able to give us minimum pumping length?

For example say we have a language L= $(10)^∗$, though for this minimal DFA will have $3$ states but NFA will have only $2$ states, which in fact is the pumping length of the language. So are NFA's able to give us exact pumping length of a language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Consider the language $L = 1^* + 0^*1^n$. The minimal NFA for $L$ has $n+C$ states for some constant $C$, but *every* word can be pumped, so the pumping length is 1.

Comment: Thanks..got it.. :)

Comment: Is $L = 1^* + 0^*1^n$ equivalent to $=1^+0^*1^$? i.e. matches words that begin with 1 end with a $1^n$? The notation in Sipser's book is a little different.

Comment: The language $L$ consists of all words of the form $1^a$ or $0^a1^n$, for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{N}$ (including $a = 0$).

Comment: Are there any counterexamples not involving a union?

Comment: Perhaps you could find one.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus. In related questions, you seem to be very knowledgeable on this topic. Is your comment more "encouraging me to work it out, as there are known solutions", or is this is a case of the unknown and there actually might not be such a counterexample? I'm currently developing a course that will briefly touch on this topic, but i'm still deeply interested in it. Again thank you for the help.

Comment: I haven’t thought about it, since my example seems simple enough. If you don’t like it, you can try finding another one yourself.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I like your solution :D I was curious whether a union was the only way to achieve p < min DFA states. However, I found one without a union! It seems $L=0^*1^*$ is a 3 state DFA where $p=1$.